# How to insert objects from a List into a table in SQL Server using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to insert a list of objects using Linq-to-SQL, and only the last object from the list gets inserted into the database. Can someone help me find the problem?

This is my code:

```
//this is the code in the orderDetailRepository class
public List < OrderDetail > CreateOrderDetailRecords(List < OrderDetail > details) {
    FruitStoreDataContext db = new FruitStoreDataContext();
    db.OrderDetails.InsertAllOnSubmit(details);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    return details;
}

//this is the code in the Form.cs file when i press the "finish button"
private void FinishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     OrderDetailRepository orderDetailRepo = new OrderDetailRepository();
     orderDetailRepo.CreateOrderDetailRecords(Ord);
     //Ord is the name of the list of OrderDetail Objects that i created...
     TotalCostLabel.Visible = true;
     TotalCostLabel.Text = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

Comment: That should work. Also, to note, you are leaking connection threads by not disposing your datacontext.

Comment: but it only inserts the last orderDetail object into the dataBase. It does not insert all the objects from the list.

Comment: What's the content of `Ord`? Did yo check if it contains multiple objects when you execute `CreateOrderDetailRecords`?

Comment: yes, actually i checked through looping through the List of objects and the list contains all the objects...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't make a new instance of the OrderDetail object every time you added it to the list and therefore only the one you recently added was inserted into the dataBase... you have to make a new OrderDetail object with the "new" key word and then it will create a new object every time you click the button and it will be added to the list. This is the correct code:

in the Form.cs.file:

```
public void ButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orderID = newOrder.OrderID;
       //Ord is the name of the List...
        if (Ord.Count == 0)
        {

            OrderRepository ordRepo = new OrderRepository();
            newOrder = new Order();
            newOrder.OrderID = orderID;
            ordRepo.NewOrder(newOrder);

        }

        newDetail= CreateOrderDetails(newOrder, b);
        Ord.Add(newDetail);

  private OrderDetail CreateOrderDetails(Order order, Button b)
    {
        var prodDict = db.Items.Select(t => new { t.Name, t.ItemID })
              .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.ItemID);
        var priceDict = db.Items.Select(t => new { t.Name, t.Price })
               .ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Price);

        OrderDetail ord = new OrderDetail();

        ord.OrderID = newOrder.OrderID;
        ord.ItemID = prodDict[b.Text];
        ord.Price =  priceDict[b.Text];
        ord.Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(QuantityTextBox.Text);
        totalCost += ord.Price * ord.Quantity;

         return ord;
  }
```

This workes perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

or there is a simpler way of doing it:

public void ButtonClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orderID = newOrder.OrderID;
       //Ord is the name of the List...
        if (Ord.Count == 0)
        {

```
        OrderRepository ordRepo = new OrderRepository();
        newOrder = new Order();
        newOrder.OrderID = orderID;
        ordRepo.NewOrder(newOrder);

    }

 Ord.Add(new OrderDetail() { OrderID = newOrder.OrderID, ItemID = prodDict[b.Text], Price = priceDict[b.Text], Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(QuantityTextBox.Text) });
```